# Apple wireless mouse and keyboard does not work

Tags: 12.04, hardware, bluetooth, magic-mouse

I paired the mouse and keyboard on Ubuntu, but it seems not work.

I got this error in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
kernel: [ 1875.935712] input: Apple Magic Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb4/4-3/4-3:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:2/input34
kernel: [ 1875.935885] evdev: no more free evdev devices
kernel: [ 1875.935893] input: failed to attach handler evdev to device input34, error: -23
kernel: [ 1875.936049] magicmouse 0005:05AC:030D.0003: input,hidraw0: BLUETOOTH HID v3.06 Mouse [Apple Magic Mouse] on 00:19:5D:0F:4A:F6


kernel: [ 2334.787710] input: Apple Wireless Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb4/4-3/4-3:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:4/input36
kernel: [ 2334.787729] evdev: no more free evdev devices
kernel: [ 2334.787737] input: failed to attach handler evdev to device input36, error: -23
kernel: [ 2334.787999] generic-bluetooth 0005:05AC:0255.0005: input,hidraw1: BLUETOOTH HID v0.50 Keyboard [Apple Wireless Keyboard] on 00:19:5D:0F:4A:F6
```

Nothing appears in `xinput --list`, only the wired mouse and keyboard.
How to fix that?

Comment: Same issue here on 12.04 64-bit, 2010 Mac mini

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug, and has been for about 2 years now, unfortunately:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/1001825

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1874245

Comment: there seems to be an actual sollution in that error-report? Some sort of script? That might be included as part of the answer, maybe someone even knows if it works?